# How do I properly pass and output my App.js to index.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I downloaded the ready webpack config from https://github.com/taniarascia/webpack-boilerplate but I can’t display my project in any way, I tried a bunch of methods, including displaying the App directly, but it gave an error.

In the js folder there are my components, the key App.js it combines all the rest

```js
//App.js
import React from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import '../styles/App.scss';

import MainPage from './MainPage';
import ChanelPage from './ChanelPage'

const App = () => {

  const [chanelData, setChanelData] = useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = useState();

  const updateDataParent = (index) => {
    setId(index)
  }

  async function getResponse() {
    let response = await fetch('https://api.json')
    let content = await response.json()
    setChanelData(content.channels)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      getResponse();
  }, [])

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<MainPage updateDataParent={updateDataParent}/>} />
                <Route path='/ChanelPage' element={<ChanelPage id={id} chanelData={chanelData}/>} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App
```

In the same js folder is exemple.js which passes itself to index.js

```js
export const example =
  () => `Sensible webpack 5 boilerplate using Babel and PostCSS with a hot dev server 
  and an optimized production build.`
```

index.js itself

```js
// Test import of a JavaScript module
import { example } from '../src/js/example'

// Test import of styles
import '@/styles/index.scss'

const heading = document.createElement('h1')
heading.textContent = example()

const app = document.querySelector('#root')
app.append(heading)
```

I will be glad for any hint even if you are not sure if it works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do **`npm start`**?

The project documentation says.

ref : https://github.com/taniarascia/webpack-boilerplate

Comment: I changed index.js and inserted App.js as I usually do. I got an error that "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx" is needed, I installed it and inserted it into babel pressers, but this did not fix my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please quote the relevant text from the link and explain why it is helpful.